# Vega drawing lines from text to origin

Tags: vega

I'm using react-vega to draw charts similar to an example on Vega's docs. I'm drawing a chart with text marks and then add some transform to them so the text wouldn't overlap each other. Here's the example:

[image]

Question: Is is possible to draw lines that connect the text to their origins? The exact position of the text isn't known since it's being moved around by Vega to avoid overlaps. Here's the desired chart:

[image]

Here's the current `marks` that draws the first chart:

```
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "dot",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "y"},
          "size": {"value": 100}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "name-label",
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "y"},
          "text": {"field": "name"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "avoidMarks": ["dot"],
          "offset": [1, 50],
          "size": {"signal": "[width + 100, height + 100]"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What needs to be added to the marks code to draw the lines connecting the text to symbols?

Comment: Take a look at reactive geometry in the Vega docs. It might be possible that way.

Comment: Don't know when this question will be reopened by the moderators again but reactive geometry is the way to go. Thanks @David.

Comment: I'd ask another question but keep just the vega tag this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David mentioned, use reactive geometry for this. Add this to the `marks` array in the example snippet above. Notice that `from.data` refers to another mark by name. `name-arrow` is then able to access the location of `name-label` and the location of the dot through `datum.x` and `datum.y`.

```
{
    "name": "name-arrow",
    "type": "rule",
    "from": {
        "data": "name-label"
    },
    "encode": {
        "enter": {
            "x": {
                "field": "x"
            },
            "x2": {
                "scale": "xscale",
                "field": "datum.x"
            },
            "y": {
                "field": "y"
            },
            "y2": {
                "scale": "yscale",
                "field": "datum.y"
            },
            "strokeWidth": {
                "value": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```